# How can I find the min of each row in two 1D arrays and sum all the mins?

Tags: go

This is what I have for the min part of the question. Can someone please help me understand the concept?

```
func MinMaxArray(arr1 [] int, arr2[]int) int {
  minA := arr1[0]
  minb := arr2[0]
  n := len(arr1[] && arr2[])
  for i:=0; i<=n ; i++{
    if arr1[i] > arr2[i] {
      max := arr1[i]
      min := arr2[i]
    } else {
      max := arr2[i]
      min := arr1[i]
    }
  }
 return min
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to keep a running tally throughout.

```golang
func MinMaxArray(arr1 []int, arr2 []int) int {
    runningTally := 0
    n := len(arr1)
    if len(arr2) < n {
        n = len(arr2)
    }
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        if arr1[i] > arr2[i] {
            runningTally += arr1[i]
        } else {
            runningTally += arr2[i]
        }
    }
    return runningTally
}
```